# Reducing the time complexity of an algorithm with nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

I have the following algorithm which I want to rewrite so it has time complexity O(n). I am new to algorithms but from my understanding since the two `for` loops both do a multiple of n iterations, the complexity will always be O(n<sup>2</sup>). Is it even possible to reduce the complexity of this?

```
Algorithm example(ArrayA, ArrayB, n)                                           
Input: 2 arrays of integers, ArrayA and ArrayB, both length n          
Output: integer

value <- 0                                                    1 operation
for i <- 0 to n-1                                             n-1 operations
    for j <- 0 to n-1                                         (n-1)^2 operations
        value <- value + (ArrayA[i] * ArrayB[j])              3(n-1)^2 operations
return value                                                  1 operation
```

Total primitive operations: n<sup>2</sup> + 2n - 1, giving it a time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

By applying a bit of algebra:

[image: algebra]

So here is an algorithm which computes the same result in O(n) time:

```py
sum_A ← 0
for i ← 0 to n-1
    sum_A ← sum_A + ArrayA[i]

sum_B ← 0
for j ← 0 to n-1
    sum_B ← sum_B + ArrayB[j]

return sum_A * sum_B
```

Generally speaking, an algorithm with nested loops cannot always be changed to reduce the time complexity; but in some cases you can do it, if you can identify something specific about the computation which means it can be done in a different way.

For sums like this, it's sometimes possible to compute the result more efficiently by writing something algebraically equivalent. So, put your mathematician's hat on when faced with such a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this makes a lot more sense. As someone who's maths skill is somewhat lacking, do you have any advice on where I could learn more about this kind of algebra?

Comment: Maths study resources aimed at late high school / early university students are probably what you should look for. The textbook [*Concrete Mathematics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics) is aimed at CS undergraduate students and has a chapter on summations, but it is not the most accessible maths textbook. There are [some recommendations on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43156/what-books-do-you-recommend-before-concrete-mathematics) which might be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation is going to only ever run in n2 time. The reason being is that you have to compare each element of i, to each element of j. For example:

```
i*j, i*j+1,...,i*j+(n-1)
(i+1)*j, (i+1)*(j+1),...,(i+1)*(j+n-1)
.
.
.
(i+n-1)*j, (i+n-1)*(j+1),...,(i+n-1)*(j+n-1)
```

There's just no way to reduce the complexity.

Comment: @MooingDuck you're right. You could limit the dataset.